# jQuery: How to animate height change without known heights?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I want to animate a height change (when i hide/show divs) using jQuery. I found some examples on SO, but I can't get those to work.

Let's say i have a container with some divs in it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">Show first div</div>
  <div class="second">Show second div</div>
  <div class="item1">
     Some text
  </div>
  <div class="item2">    
     Some multiline<br />text
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.first').on('click',function(){
  $('.item2').hide();
  $('.item1').show();
});
$('.second').on('click',function(){
  $('.item1').hide();
  $('.item2').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ytW69/2/

When I click the div .first, I want to show the div .item1, when I click the div .second, I want to show the div .item2. The height of these divs differs, which means the size of the container changes when I hide/display the divs.

How can I animate this height change, without knowing the size of any div?

ps. if there is a CSS solution, that would be even better. I don't think it is possible with just CSS tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the optional parameter of [**`.show()`**](https://api.jquery.com/show/) and [**`.hide()`**](https://api.jquery.com/hide/), you can achieve the animation effect that you want. you can pass that parameter as `milliseconds` too.

Try,

```
$('.first').on('click',function(){
    $('.item2').hide('slow');
    $('.item1').show('slow');
});
$('.second').on('click',function(){
    $('.item1').hide('slow');
    $('.item2').show('slow');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/ytW69/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
$('.first').on('click',function(){
    $('.item2').hide('fast');
    $('.item1').show('fast');
});
$('.second').on('click',function(){
    $('.item1').hide('fast');
    $('.item2').show('fast');
});
```

When you provide string values like **fast** and **slow** then `.show()` becomes an animation method. The `.show()` method animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want better looking effect (in my opinion), you can use `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`:

```
$('.first').on('click', function () {
    $('.item1:hidden').slideDown('slow');
    $('.item2:visible').slideUp('slow');
});

$('.second').on('click', function () {
    $('.item2:hidden').slideDown('slow');
    $('.item1:visible').slideUp('slow');
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JT54y/) demo for result.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS solution that you are looking for is playing with max-height and/or min-height.
this might help:
[css3 height transition on an absolute positioned div to overflow auto fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750418/css3-height-transition-on-an-absolute-positioned-div-to-overflow-auto-fails/21750488#21750488)

Comment: I came across some solutions which used max/min-height. However my pages can't have a height, not even a max-height